# why won't pandas equations use the values in the columns

Tags: python, pandas, equation

I have a dataframe with numbers, and they are printed out using the print command so I know it is in the dataframe. But when I do my equations and my conditional they are not in the variables.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('Cam_practice1.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['x_block', 'y_block'])

print(df)
equation_x = ((df.x_block))**2
equation_y = ((df.y_block))**2
eq = equation_x + equation_y

if eq  <=4 :
    df.to_csv('gridoutput.csv')
```

What I want is with the complete formula eq, when that value is less than or equal to 4 I want the row to written to a new output. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
equation_x = ((df.x_block))**2
equation_y = ((df.y_block))**2
eq = equation_x + equation_y
df[eq<=4].to_csv('gridoutput.csv')
```

Comment: that looks like it will work but when I do it nothing gets outputted to the new file.

Comment: Not looks like, i tested it  and it outputs correctly, what does your data look like, do you have any values that are less than 4?

Comment: Thanks for your help I figured it out... it was my fault.